# Multilingual support with unicode characters. A little confusion

Tags: php, unicode, multilingual

I am creating a web application framework, in which I am providing support for multilingual content.
I mean a content, say a paragraph can have 2 sentences in English and other 2 sentences in Hindi (an indian language). Now I have several doubts about that.

1) User or admin will add that content to the website. They will be presented a textarea (where they can paste their content). Then they submit the post and I will save the content in a database. I also want to provide them a web based typewriter interface where they can type content in a given language, copy it from there, and then put it back in my main textarea.
Doubt: 
1a) Will I need to do something to the textarea, so that it will accept characters in unicode.
1b) Where can I find a typewriter interface for some language I desire. Does tinymce supports that.
1c) I should put the encoding of database as 'UTF 8', right?

2) Then I nead to get content from database and put it in a webpage and show it. Now this content has utf8 encoding. As it can have many languages. What should I need  to do? I am guessing that just setting encoding of the webpage as utf-8 will do. What will happen if the font that is required by a language is not installed on clients pc?

I am using PhpEd editor. Should my php files encoding must be utf-8, or just specifying the html encoding tag as utf8 will be enough?

I am a bit stumped. Please help.

Comment: What is a typewriter interface?

Comment: This is a programming website.  You don't need to tell us what Hindi is.  :-)

Comment: By typewriter interface means that a general typewrite for many languages.
See this link:
http://kaulonline.com/uninagari/default/

Now, when admin wants to put some content in hindi, he can just use it and type the content, and put it back in main textbox. 
If I can provide such interface for all required languages, admin will just use the admin panel to enter content in many languages.

Comment: That "virtual keyboard" approach might work for Hindi, but it's going to be near impossible for Japanese and Chinese, since you'd need an extensive database of Kanji/Hanzi readings (including compound readings) to process the input. Why not just let the user change the keyboard layout on their local machine and let the OS handle it? If they speak the language well enough to write it, it's entirely likely they've added the keyboard layout anyway, and you're not going to end up in a situation where you'll need to write a complete IME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1a) Yes, if the text area will accept text in any language, as long as you have the web page that contains it encoded in UTF-8. If it doesn't work, double check both the HTTP Content-type header, and the HTML META http-equiv tag for Content-type. If they are both present, they should agree; one of them would be sufficient.

1c) what to do with your database depends on the specific DBMS you use. If supported, make sure that

```
1. the table encoding
2. the connection/the client encoding
```

are both set to UTF-8.

2) Again, set the page encoding to UTF-8 (see 1a). If there are no sufficient fonts on the client system, you lose - but likely, if that's the case, the end user wouldn't have been able to read the text, anyway (most users do have fonts for text in their native languages).

The encoding of the PHP files is only relevant if they contain non-ASCII text (which you should avoid).